# Slick Carousel dragging event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a parallax slick carousel. I am trying to find out how you can go about activating the parallax during a drag. I think its activating during a slide when you click on the arrows.

http://jsfiddle.net/ayve1nmf/27/

```
// On before slide change
 $('.data').on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    console.log("beforeChange");
     //console.log(nextSlide);
     parallaxAnimate(this, currentSlide, nextSlide);
 });
```

Comment: here is a new jsfiddle with the drag properties in place. http://jsfiddle.net/ayve1nmf/173/

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to apply your own dragstart or dragging event(s). It's pretty easy, the basics of it would be something like this

```
// Event to initiate drag, include touchstart events
$('.data').on('mousedown', function(e){

 // Drag start logic
 // ...

 // Event to end drag, may want to include touchend events
 $(this).one('mouseup', function(e){

  $(this).off('mousemove');
  // Drag stop logic
  // ...

 }).on('mousemove', function(e){

  // Logic for dragging, can get mouse position
  // will probably want to throttle
  // possibly include touchmove events also
  console.log(e.pageX);

 });

});
```

### Complete Example

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

//

     
     $('.data').slick();


     /*
    startDragPosition = event.pageX;
    $mover.bind(
        'mousemove',
        function( e ) {
            $mover.css({
                'marginLeft': -(300 + startDragPosition - e.pageX)
            });
        }
    );*/
       
    
    var parallaxAnimate = function(el, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        console.log("parallax animate");

        var increment = "+";

         if (currentSlide > nextSlide) {
             increment = "-";
         }

         $(el).find(".parallaxback img:visible").animate({
             left: increment + "=15"
         }, 400, function () {
             // Animation complete.
         });       
    };



     // On edge hit
     $('.data').on('mousemove', function (e) {
        //console.log('mousemove', e);
     });


     // On breakpoint event
     $('.data').on('breakpoint', function (event, slick, breakpoint) {
         console.log("breakpoint", breakpoint);         
     });

     // On swipe event
     $('.data').on('swipe', function (event, slick, direction) {
         console.log(direction);
         
     });

     // On edge hit
     $('.data').on('edge', function (event, slick, direction) {
        // console.log('edge was hit')
     });




     // On after slide change
     $('.data').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide) {
         console.log("afterChange");
         //parallaxAnimate(this, currentSlide, nextSlide);
     });

     // On before slide change
     $('.data').on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        console.log("beforeChange");
         //console.log(nextSlide);
         parallaxAnimate(this, currentSlide, nextSlide);
     });
     
    // Fiddle me this...
    // Event to initiate drag, include touchstart events
    $('.data').on('mousedown', function(e){

     // Drag start logic
     // ...
     console.log('drag has started');

     // Event to end drag, may want to include touchend events
     $(this).one('mouseup', function(e){

      $(this).off('mousemove');
      // Drag stop logic
      // ...
      
      console.log('drag has stopped');

     }).on('mousemove', function(e){

      // Logic for dragging, can get mouse position
      // will probably want to throttle
      // possibly include touchmove events also
      console.log('drag move', e.pageX);

     });

    });

            

 });
```

```css
.container{
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.block {
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    height: 170px;
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    background: grey;
}
.parallaxback {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.parallaxback img {
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    left:-50px;
}
.slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top:-20px;
}
.slick-prev {
    left:0;
}
.slick-next {
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" />
 <h2>Carosuel</h2>

<div class="container">

<div class="data" data-slick='{ "infinite": false, "slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 2}'>
    <div class="block">
         <h3>1</h3>

        <div class="parallaxback">
            <img src="http://www.mrgraymedia.co.uk/gcsemedia/images/comics/captainamerica.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
         <h3>2</h3>

        <div class="parallaxback">
            <img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/6/67663/3439485-03c.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
         <h3>3</h3>

        <div class="parallaxback">
            <img src="http://blog.1979semifinalist.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/093-john-byrne.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
         <h3>4</h3>

        <div class="parallaxback">
            <img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/6/66303/3481801-detective+01.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
         <h3>5</h3>

        <div class="parallaxback">
            <img src="https://superherogeorge.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/iron-man-peel-and-stick-comic-book-cover-900x1288.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
         <h3>6</h3>

        <div class="parallaxback">
            <img src="http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/underwire/2009/12/1982-wolverine-1-4.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
         <h3>7</h3>

        <div class="parallaxback">
            <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m7hijdSwXT1qdyv2wo1_1280.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
         <h3>8</h3>

        <div class="parallaxback">
            <img src="http://melleum.com/data/uploads/11/299782-comic-book.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
         <h3>9</h3>

        <div class="parallaxback">
            <img src="http://www.mrgraymedia.co.uk/gcsemedia/images/comics/hulk.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        
        </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle for it

Comment: sure thing, updated with jsfiddle-- check the console.log

Comment: I mean its not integrated with the slider carousel though to control the parallax, to test this out. Wouldn't it include animating the background images in a step animation?

Comment: I've adapted it - is this correct - http://jsfiddle.net/ayve1nmf/173/  -- is it animating in the right direction - how could we improve the code to toggle to increment up or down

Comment: also locking off the image so it doesn't keep floating past its edge would be good and resetting unseen images so the parallax continues to have an affect

Comment: these are merely the basic hooks for you to perform drag related logic-- in your case parallax effects. slick doesn't provide these hooks because they're trivial to implement and don't represent the core functionality of the slick carousel. outside of calculating precise limits and offsets for each of your images to give you the desire parallax effect during move event, you could use something like GSAP to tween them automagically.

Comment: to determine scroll direction in order to increment/decrement you would simply cache the last e.pageX and compare the last `e.pageX` to the current `e.pageX`, `if(last < current) direction = 'right'` `if(last > current) direction = 'left'` and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('swipe', '.slick-slider', function(event, slick, direction){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```